# Packages missing in current osx-64 and channels

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

After trying to recreate an environment using a file I got this error:

`Error: Packages missing in current osx-64 channels:
  - timbr-io::argh 0.26.1 py27_0
  - timbr-io::pathtools 0.1.2 py27_0
  - timbr-io::watchdog 0.8.3 py27_0`

And the same error running those commands on a docker container.

`Error:  Packages missing in current linux-64 channels:
  - timbr-io::argh 0.26.1 py27_0
  - timbr-io::pathtools 0.1.2 py27_0
  - timbr-io::watchdog 0.8.3 py27_0`

This is the file I'm using as a source:

`name: snowflakes
dependencies:
- boto3=1.3.1=py27_0
- botocore=1.4.28=py27_0
- docutils=0.12=py27_2
- ecdsa=0.13=py27_0
- futures=3.0.5=py27_0
- jmespath=0.9.0=py27_0
- openssl=1.0.2h=1
- paramiko=1.16.0=py27_0
- pip=8.1.2=py27_0
- pycrypto=2.6.1=py27_4
- python=2.7.12=1
- python-dateutil=2.5.3=py27_0
- pyyaml=3.11=py27_4
- readline=6.2=2
- setuptools=23.0.0=py27_0
- six=1.10.0=py27_0
- sqlite=3.13.0=0
- timbr-io::argh=0.26.1=py27_0
- timbr-io::pathtools=0.1.2=py27_0
- timbr-io::watchdog=0.8.3=py27_0
- tk=8.5.18=0
- wheel=0.29.0=py27_0
- yaml=0.1.6=0
- zlib=1.2.8=3
- pip:
  - argh==0.26.1
  - pathtools==0.1.2
  - watchdog==0.8.3`

**Note:** I actually create this file running the following commands, the problem is when I try to recreate this environment.

`conda create --name snowflakes boto3 paramiko
source activate snowflakes
conda install -c timbr-io watchdog
conda env export > environment.yml`

As you can see I'm installing `watchdog` from `timbr-io` (in anaconda.org), which have linux-64 and osx-64 versions of it ([timbr-io/watchdog](http://anaconda.org/timbr-io/watchdog)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot take a conda environment exported from one Operating System and use it on another.

The package numbers (and in some cases the package existence) are not aligned on different platforms.

`conda env export` is so you can reproduce the same env on that same OS.